# How can I create a single hyperlinked PDF containing content from 2 different Websites?

Tags: web-crawler, pdf-generation

I have a particular use case and after some online searching suspect there is no pre-built solution, so I'm curious what you would recommend for implementing this.

I have a Table of Contents on domain A (https://true-freedom.net/) and each entry of the TOC links to exactly one post on domain B (https://www.quora.com/).

My goal is to create a single PDF of both the TOC on domain A as well as the individual posts on domain B, with intra-PDF links from the TOC to the posts, all within the same PDF.

Which tool, language, library, etc would you use to do this, and why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting this question I signed up to ChatGPT and the first question I asked was the question I posted above. I was impressed with the answer and the code example it provided.

The basic approach was the following (using Python):

With BeautifulSoup, get all the links from the table of contents page:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
post_urls = [link["href"] for link in soup.find_all("a") if "quora.com" in link["href"]]
```

then create a single HTML file containing both the TOC and the content from the links in the TOC.

Create anchor links between the TOC and the individual posts.

Then use `wkhtmltopdf` to convert the final html file to pdf:

```
subprocess.run(["wkhtmltopdf", "all.html", "output.pdf"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a web crawler, set to explore only to depth one, starting at the table of contents page.

This might yield a folder full of HTML files, of which one is the 'root', and maybe some CSS files. Image files would be a problem, because their names might clash. Maybe you don't need them.

Then, perhaps you can find a tool to combine all these HTML files into one. Not sure such a tool even exists.

Then, it's time to convert to PDF. At this point, all the links are internal: no problem.

The obvious suggestion - convert a series of HTML files to PDF whilst simultaneously preserving crosslinks - does seem a bit far-fetched. But perhaps it exists - who knows?